# Python multiprocessing how to update a complex object in a manager list without using .join() method

Tags: python-multiprocessing, telegram, python-3.7, python-multithreading

I started programming in Python about 2 months ago and I've been struggling with this problem in the last 2 weeks.
I know there are many similar threads to this one but I can't really find a solution which suits my case.

I need to have the main process which is the one which interacts with Telegram and another process, buffer, which understands the complex object received from the main and updates it.

I'd like to do this in a simpler and smoother way.

At the moment objects are not being updated due to the use of multi-processing without the join() method.

I tried then to use multi-threading instead but it gives me compatibility problems with Pyrogram a framework which i am using to interact with Telegram.

I wrote again the "complexity" of my project in order to reproduce the same error I am getting and in order to get and give the best help possible from and for everyone.

a.py

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, length = -1, height = -1):
        self.length = length
        self.height = height
```

b.py

```
from a import A
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, length = -1, height = -1, width = -1):
        super().__init__(length = -1, height = -1)
        self.length = length
        self.height = height
        self.width = width

    def setHeight(self, value):
        self.height = value
```

c.py

```
class C():
    def __init__(self, a, x = 0, y = 0):
        self.a = a
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def func1(self):
        if self.x < 7:
            self.x = 7
```

d.py

```
from c import C
class D(C):
    def __init__(self, a, x = 0, y = 0, z = 0):
        super().__init__(a, x = 0, y = 0)
        self.a = a
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    def func2(self):
        self.func1()
```

main.py

```
from b import B
from d import D
from  multiprocessing import Process, Manager
from buffer import buffer

if __name__ == "__main__":

    manager = Manager()
    lizt = manager.list()

    buffer = Process(target = buffer, args = (lizt, )) #passing the list as a parameter
    buffer.start()
    #can't invoke buffer.join() here because I need the below code to keep running while the buffer process takes a few minutes to end an instance passed in the list
    #hence I can't wait the join() function to update the objects inside the buffer but i need objects updated in order to pop them out from the list

    import datetime as dt
    t = dt.datetime.now()

    #library of kind of multithreading (pool of 4 processes), uses asyncio lib
    #this while was put to reproduce the same error I am getting

    while True:
        if t + dt.timedelta(seconds = 10) < dt.datetime.now():
            lizt.append(D(B(5, 5, 5)))
            t = dt.datetime.now()


"""
#This is the code which looks like the one in my project

#main.py
from pyrogram import Client #library of kind of multithreading (pool of 4 processes), uses asyncio lib
from b import B
from d import D
from  multiprocessing import Process, Manager
from buffer import buffer

if __name__ == "__main__":

    api_id = 1234567
    api_hash = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
    app = Client("my_account", api_id, api_hash)

    manager = Manager()
    lizt = manager.list()

    buffer = Process(target = buffer, args = (lizt, )) #passing the list as a parameter
    buffer.start()
    #can't invoke buffer.join() here because I need the below code to run at the same time as the buffer process
    #hence I can't wait the join() function to update the objects inside the buffer

@app.on_message()
def my_handler(client, message):
    lizt.append(complex_object_conatining_message)
"""
```

buffer.py

```
def buffer(buffer):
    print("buffer was defined")
    while True:
        if len(buffer) > 0:
            print(buffer[0].x) #prints 0
            buffer[0].func2() #this changes the class attribute locally in the class instance but not in here
            print(buffer[0].x) #prints 0, but I'd like it to be 7

            print(buffer[0].a.height) #prints 5
            buffer[0].a.setHeight(10) #and this has the same behaviour
            print(buffer[0].a.height) #prints 5 but I'd like it to be 10

            buffer.pop(0)
```

This is the whole code about the problem I am having.
Literally every suggestion is welcome, hopefully constructive, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I had to change the way to solve this problem, which was using asyncio like the framework was doing as well.

This solution offers everything I was looking for:

-complex objects update

-avoiding the problems of multiprocessing (in particular with join())

It is also:

-lightweight: before I had 2 python processes 1) about 40K 2) about 75K

This actual process is about 30K (and it's also faster and cleaner)

Here's the solution, I hope it will be useful for someone else like it was for me:

*The part of the classes is skipped because this solution updates complex objects absolutely fine*

main.py

```
from pyrogram import Client
import asyncio
import time

def cancel_tasks():
    #get all task in current loop
    tasks = asyncio.Task.all_tasks()
    for t in tasks:
        t.cancel()

try:
    buffer = []
    firstWorker(buffer) #this one is the old buffer.py file and function
    #the missing loop and loop method are explained in the next piece of code
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("")
finally:
    print("Closing Loop")
    cancel_tasks()
```

firstWorker.py

```
import asyncio
def firstWorker(buffer):
    print("First Worker Executed")

    api_id = 1234567
    api_hash = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
    app = Client("my_account", api_id, api_hash)

    @app.on_message()
    async def my_handler(client, message):
        print("Message Arrived")
        buffer.append(complex_object_conatining_message)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

    app.run(secondWorker(buffer)) #here is the trick: I changed the 
                                  #method run() of the Client class 
                                  #inside the Pyrogram framework 
                                  #since it was a loop itself. 
                                  #In this way I added another task 
                                  #to the existing loop in orther to 
                                  #let run both of them together.
```

my secondWorker.py

```
import asyncio
async def secondWorker(buffer):
    while True:
        if len(buffer) > 0:
            print(buffer.pop(0))

        await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

The resources to understand the asyncio used in this code can be found here:

[Asyncio simple tutorial](https://tutorialedge.net/python/concurrency/asyncio-event-loops-tutorial/)

[Python Asyncio Official Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-llapi-index.html)

[This tutorial about how to fix classical Asyncio errors](https://xinhuang.github.io/posts/2017-07-31-common-mistakes-using-python3-asyncio.html)